# VBA: Is it possible to use .MoveStartUntil with the cset is a word?

Tags: vba

Is it possible to use .MoveStartUntil with the Cset is equal to a word? Like for example,

```
With Selection
    .MoveStartUntil cset:="Why", count:=wdBackward
End With
```

The problem is that it only go backward until any of the letters in the word "Why" is encountered so if it encounter other words that has a "W", "h" or "y" in it, it stop there. Is there a way to make it move to start until it reaches the specific word and not by the letters of the given word? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Programming documentation is like a statue law. It says only what it means.

> Moves the start position of the specified range or selection **until one of the specified characters** is found in the document. If the movement is backward through the document, the range or selection is expanded.

Any observed behaviour, not documented, is not to be used.

It's is a contract. Follow the rules and your program should work forever.

Comment: Is there other way to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Use find like you would at the keyboard. Record it and get the code for it as well. It appears to be a command for finding multiple delimiters.